# How can I programmatically insert/update thousands of nodes?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have to insert 2k nodes with my custom module but it takes forever.
I know there is a way to delete a lot of nodes with only one operation:

```
$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node");
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery("node")
->condition('type', 'node_type' )
->execute();
$fc = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($result);
$storage_handler->delete($fc);
```

I guess there is also a way to insert them with only one operation (and also a way to update them). How can I achieve that?

I get datas from API and for each set of data, i have to create a node. for the moment, this is what i do

```
foreach($datas as $data)
{
    $node = Node::create(['type'=>'node_type']); 
    $node->set('my_field', $data); 
    $node->save()
}
```

And here's an exemple of how I deactivate thousands of nodes

```
$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node");
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery("node")
    ->condition('type', 'node_type' )
    ->condition('status', true)
    ->execute()
;
$nodes = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($result);
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $node->setPublished(false);
    $node->save();
}
```

it takes way too long for a simple update query

Comment: Did you look at the Migrate or Feeds modules?

Comment: Yeah, look at Migrate or Feeds first. It's unclear where these nodes are coming from. And if you want to update existing nodes, how you want to do the matching. If you want to do that on your own from within a custom module you need to provide a batch process updating that many nodes at once. To have them processed in chunks. You could do that either from a custom form that then can be triggered manually or from `hook_update_N(&$sandbox)` or even better `hook_deploy_NAME(&$sandbox)` (or at least `hook_post_update_NAME(&$sandbox)` if you don't use `drush deploy`, yet).

Comment: i can't use a module to achieve this, i have to do it with my own custom one

Comment: This is a clear example for batch operations / possibly a drush command to initiate it. There is no way to do this in a single op with the <=60 second operation limit on most servers. There should be a cron task to fetch the API data and store that in queue jobs, then batch process those jobs.

Comment: _it takes way too long for a simple update query_ That’s the disconnect - this isn’t a simple update query, Drupal doesn’t store entity data in a single table. The trade off between you coding this all yourself and having a ready-made system which does everything for you, is performance. There isn’t really a way to speed this up without writing the databases queries yourself, and making peace with the fact that the system won’t be able to listen to the create/update events and respond like it normally would. This may not be a problem, but depends on your specific site configuration